# Is it worth replacing argument in a switch with a constant?

Tags: c++, optimization, switch-statement

In my code I have

```
switch (cd->op)
{
...
}
```

and I'm wondering whether I should do

```
CalcWizConsts::eqOps thisOp = cd->op;
switch (thisOp)
{
...
}
```

Comment: What type is op? Making a local variable doesn't make op a const.

Comment: Why would you inject another identifier name into the scope when it's not really needed?

Comment: You tagged "optimization".  If you believe that that kind of change is going to speed up your code, you are wasting your time.  Premature optimization is the root of all evil.  Don't even consider doing that until it becomes a problem, which it almost definitely won't.

Comment: How do you mean "constant"? There is no need to add the local temporary unless it makes your code more readable. And what's the optimization tag for?

Comment: In any case where it seems "obvious" that making a minor code change will make things fast, you have to consider that compiler writers would also see it as "obvious", and would have made the compiler do it for you.

Answer (score 8):

The argument to `switch` will only be evaluated once, so there is no need to store it in a temporary first. There is no performance difference, and you don't have to worry about changing the value in one of the `case` clauses either. The only reason I can think of for assigning to a variable first is to make the code more readable, if the expression is lengthy.

Comment: Assigning it to a local can also give it a locally meaningful name, making the code more self-commenting.

Comment: It can also make it *less* readable. Like in the case here, `thisOp` is inferior to the original, `cd->op`.